# If $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)+g(x)]=2$ and $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)-g(x)]=1$,then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)$

Tags: limits

If $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)+g(x)]=2$ and $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)-g(x)]=1$,then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)$
$(A)\text{need not exist}\hspace{1cm}(B)\text{exist and is}\frac{3}{4}\hspace{1cm}(C)\text{exists and is}\frac{-3}{4}\hspace{1cm}(D)\text{exists and is}\frac{4}{3}$

---

If i add and subtract the two given equation,i find $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\frac{3}{2}$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=\frac{1}{2}$.
It appears that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=\frac{3}{4}$ but i am not sure.I doubt whether the $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)$ need not exist may be the answer.Any comments or explanation is required.

Comment: if the limits of $f$ and $g$ exist, then the limit of the product of $f$ and $g$ must exist too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(f(x)+g(x))^2 - (f(x)-g(x))^2= 4f(x)g(x)$ so the limit is $3/4$.